# Code Reuse , Threading Class

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

C#

What type of winforms or controls implement "Invoke/BeginInvoke" functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) itself implements [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx), which is where the `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` methods come from.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that inherits [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). `Form` and `UserControl` are the two classes where you'll use them the most.